# React Context outside of React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, state

I am attempting to replace redux with react context in my new app.

Previously I used to save my user access token in redux state and was able to access that token in redux actions for future API calls.

Now I have a new ApiClient class outside of react. I have to pass the user token for each request from my consumer component.

I am looking for a way so I don't have to pass this token each time I make a new API call.

Thanks

Comment: No there isn't a way yet to do that. All the more reason not to quit redux

Comment: Thats bad. Was just trying to avoid redux boilerplate.

Comment: @gamingumar : while it's not specifically related to your original question, you might want to check out our new [Redux Starter Kit package](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org), which can simplify a lot of use cases.